# Why WebLogic is stopping long running threads without throwing any Exception?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have one Java application(Deployed on WebLogic) which I use for polling messages from Amazon FIFO but problem is that after running for a long time Whatever WebLogic is doing my thread behaves like a hibernated thread and my application stops polling messages without any exception.

Comment: Weblogic does not stop any application thread itself.
Take thread dumps when the issue occurs to see threads activities.

Comment: I understand this point but somehow when ever my servers goes to any warning state/ run the application continuously on same thread for days say(7 days) then this problem happens

Comment: take several thread dumps when you server in going to warning state